# How to extend a standard SAP Fiori freestyle application with VS code?

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

I understand that you can create an adaption project in BAS:

https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP%20Business%20Application%20Studio/584e0bcbfd4a4aff91c815cefa0bce2d/ada9567b767941aba8d49fdb4fdedea7.html

But how is this done in VS code? I have looked into the 'Easy UI5 Generator' but could not find a proper template.

https://github.com/SAP/generator-easy-ui5/

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no extension available for creating Adaptation Project in VS Code but can only be done via BAS. But it is on the roadmap (see [here](https://roadmaps.sap.com/board?PRODUCT=7355490010080000136&PRODUCT=73554900100800001361&range=FIRST-LAST#Q3%202022;INNO=000D3AA914A11EECABE73579E9FB7717)).